# Joomla 2.5 core installation database problems

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I'm in quite a bit of a bind. I've got a copy of joomla 2.5 that I've been working with as a test environment for a site redesign. However, there was an issue, and one of the developers on my team "accidentally" (don't even get me started, here) deleted a row in one of the databases for the installation. Now, all of the content edit screens are essentially broken.

I have NO IDEA what specifically was deleted nor do I know from what table, and we don't have a workable backup from before this screw up.

From the front end, nothing at all appears amiss (every page with every bit of content is just fine), so it was definitely a core installation database row that was deleted.

Is there any (free) solution that anyone could suggest to remedy this situation? Would it be possible to simply copy the existing content from the database to a fresh installation, along with the core files (if so, could someone shed some light as to which tables we should be copying to the fresh installation)?

Comment: I have NO IDEA what specifically was deleted nor do I know from what table. All I know is that something was deleted, from one of the tables and now the content edit screens are broken.

Comment: Than you might need a tool to compare the schema between the two databases (the broken one and one valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no solution to remedy your situation, But i guess you could do it by hand by following these steps:

1. Transfer all new contents table to the new installation.
2. Keep attention for Joomla tables like (#_*extensions, #*_assets, #__schema ...).
3. Try to merge between the old Joomla tables and new one.

Comment: It took quite some time, but I was finally able to recover my tables. It sucked having to go the long way around, but as is life, I suppose